# Omitting core dumps via C a #define (or other in code/compile time solutions)?

Tags: c++, c, bitcoin, coredump, crash-dumps

I understand that the operating system generates a core dump sometimes when a signal is sent (usually upon a crash).  Is there a way to tell the operating system from *inside* C/C++ via a #define or compiler flag that no, or a somehow **specifically limited** core dump can be generated via that executable?  The only way I know of to control it is via ulimit -c.  My test system is Linux.  The no core dump does not need to be implemented system wide, only for a specific program.

For the interested, this has to do with [CVE-2019-15947](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-15947) in Bitcoin Core's bitcoin-qt which still has no solution.

Some of this discussion is at the [Bitcoin GitHub bug tracking page](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/16824).

The other option would be to obfunscate and or encrypt the wallet.dat in memory so it's not easily retrievable via core dumps.  Please note the second option can already be accomplished, though is not enabled by default.

Comment: Have you investigated setrlimit() and it's RLIMIT_CORE parameter?  There are plenty of runtime ways to turn off cores, but probably none that are as simple as a compiler flag.

Comment: Briefly, yes, but I couldn't get RLIMIT_CORE to work on my test case.

Comment: No, not really.  You can make it hard, you can do things like set core file size limit to zero or handle `SIGSEGV` yourself, but if your code is running on my system, using my libraries, running under my kernel, and I want your code to dump core when it gets a `SIGSEGV`, it's going to dump core when it gets a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: create a directory named "coredump" in the current directory?

Comment: I see. I would think some type of encryption (which is in place, but optional and often not used) against the wallet.dat's is the best bet.  Then the wallet and priv keys would have to be recovered and decrypted.  So if it does dump core, it won't dump a retrievable wallet.dat within the core to another part of the system, or upload to where misc users can access it on a bug tracker.

Comment: @oxagast Pretty much.  And you need to be sure the keys aren't also in memory any longer than necessary to encrypt/decrypt the data you want to protect - that's not as easy as it seems - [`memset()` calls that only effect memory that gets freed, for example, can be elided by optimizing compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538366/can-memset-function-call-be-removed-by-compiler).

Comment: Also telling it not to dump core at all is... not ideal, anyway.  Bitcoin isn't a trivial program and debugging from core dumps is sometimes necessary anyway.  I'm also thinking when a user crashes it, they'll have no saved backtrace to send to devs.

Comment: There are third party products which aim to solve this exact problem of securing crypto keys within running SW. I won't advertise any particular product but just FYI in case you want to do your own research on whether that is a viable approach for your situation.

Comment: @oxagast Is the key stored in a global variable?

Comment: There are also side channel attacks. Ssh stores keys encrypted in memory with a big enough key [this](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=156109087822676&w=2).

Comment: I don't know why `setrlimit` wouldn't work.  Can you post your complete test case and explain what happened when you ran it?

Comment: In fact it did work in [my test](https://gist.github.com/neldredge/fbe678dcf66975f8516399d6897c2a34).  You still get the message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` but no core file is actually produced.

Comment: @NateEldredge Did you check coredumpctl if you have that on your system?  I still get the core dumped message, so I checked (https://termbin.com/h0sm) and saw it still did produce a core.

Comment: @oxagast: I don't have coredumpctl installed.  I just saw that without setrlimit it created a `core` file in the current working directory, and with setrlimit it did not.

Comment: It looks like you are asking two questions; for this to be a useful question on SO, the 'other option' paragraph should be removed (into another question, if you can make it a specific question about programming, but I fear it falls into the category of asking us to implement an entire system). If the question is to be one question, it would be: how do I stop a program from generating a coredump file when it segfaults?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "in code/compile-time", you can install a signal handler and wipe memory upon receiving that signal.

However, crashes are handled by the kernel, not the compiler or the executable. You cannot stop memory from being dumped by the kernel into a core from inside the executable, no matter what you do.

Therefore, the other option sounds best.

Comment: Weather the debugging info (ex. -ggdb) is compiled into the binary is irrelevant to weather it dumps core.  As in you could compile with -ggdb0 (or flag at all) and it can still dump core, just not with the extra symbols.

Comment: @oxagast Thanks, removed. Can you please respond to my comment on the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible to set the limit from within a program with `setrlimit()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <errno.h>


int setNoCores( void )
{
    int result;
    struct rlimit core_limiter;

    core_limiter.rlim_cur = 0;    // *no* core
    core_limiter.rlim_max = 0;

    // Tell the OS no core-files
    result = setrlimit( RLIMIT_CORE, &core_limiter );

    // Was it OK for you?
    if ( result != 0 )
    {
        switch( errno )
        {
            case EFAULT:   fprintf( stderr, "setNoCores() - EFAULT\n" ); break;
            case EINVAL:   fprintf( stderr, "setNoCores() - EINVAL\n" ); break;
            case EPERM:    fprintf( stderr, "setNoCores() - EPERM - No Permissions!\n" ); break;
            case ESRCH:    fprintf( stderr, "setNoCores() - ESRCH\n" ); break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if ( setNoCores() == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Core Files off\n") ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Failed to change limits, core-file generation at default\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the process needs *permission* to adjust the limits.  Depending on the user-id, the request may be denied, and `EPERM` error set.

Core files are also controllable in your OS via the `ulimit` command.  With the `-c` parameter, this sets the *maximum* size of the core file.  The size-number is the number of 1024 or 512-byte blocks [ref: Solaris man page (512), Linux '--help' (1024)].  Setting this in the shell the program executes from should limit the result for only that shells child-processes.

For no core-files:

```
    ulimit -c 0
```

To turn it back on again:

```
ulimit -c <some large number>
```

For more details, try `ulimit --help` in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

The [key primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089633/avoid-dumping-information-in-a-core-file) you will want to use is [`madvise(..., MADV_DONTDUMP)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), which notifies Linux (since 3.4) that you do not wish a series of pages to be included in the dump. The flag is also called `VM_DONTDUMP` in kernel space. (Note that some versions of gdb [do not respect](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1518243) this flag, which could be relevant for cores generated by `gcore` or other helpers rather than by the kernel.)

You will also need to ensure that when processing keys and other sensitive data stored in these pages information is not disclosed via registers or spilled to the stack sufficient for a compromise should a core dump after that time.

Comment: It's pretty hard to process keys without ever having them in registers...

Comment: But this is Linux-specific. I think Bitcoin is trying to be somewhat portable.

Comment: As far as being Linux specific, I think there are similar things mentioned in the GitHub thread about MAP_CONCEAL and MAP_NOCORE under some BSDs.  Not sure how Windows handles this stuff.  It's also probably pretty client specific.

Comment: @NateEldredge well, that's why I said "sufficient for a compromise" - if a key is 1024 bits long but you only process 64 bits at a time that would be safer (as long as an attacker can't force repeated crashes). Problem would be if the compiler auto-vectorizes your code and you end up with half the key in an AVX register.